# Perchè tanti dicono "tipologia" e non dicono "tipo"?

Tags: word-choice

Devo comprare un frullatore, sono andata su internet a capire il migliore. Ho visto modelli, poi ho chiesto al mio amico quale "tipologia" è meglio, e lui sè arrabbiato!

Ho detto la parola è su internet, e lui ha detto
gli italiani sono ignoranti e usano parole difficili
e non sanno cosa vuol dire e le dicono per confondere
i clienti. Ho capito che non è arrabbiato di me.

Qui vedi la parola:
https://www.sceltaideale.it/frullatore-ad-immersione/
e anche qui:
https://frullatoreadimmersione.eu/ però di "ingrediente".

Io non lo so, sul vocabolario "tipologia" è difficile, non è uguale a "tipo", e perchè la usano? E perchè il mio amico si arrabbia? E grave dire "tipologia" o è grave che qualcuno si arrabbia?

Comment: Arrabbiarsi non serve a niente, ma il tuo amico fa bene a farti notare che alcune parole, per non avendo molto senso, vengono usate perché si pensa che suonino meglio di altre. :)

Comment: Per non avere molto senso? Io credo, vengono usate, per avere più senso, non meno. Dirò al mio amico che non si arrabbia, ma poi forse si arrabbia di te... ha ha, grazie @DaG.

Comment: Scusa, @micina96, avevo scritto male: doveva essere “_pur_ non avendo...”. Voglio dire che, per esempio, “tipo” avrebbe un significato più preciso di “tipologia” parlando di frullatori o lampadine, eppure qualcuno usa una parola meno adatta pensando che suoni meglio.

Comment: Ahh, @dag, potevo capire, sì, ma l'italiano è cosi difficile. A parlare è diverso, capisco meglio. Ho detto al mio amico di non arrabbiarsi, lui ha detto "quando ci uole ci uole", allora ho scelto un argomento diverso...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questo estratto da [dizionari.corriere.it](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/T/tipologia.shtml) spiega la differenza tra i due termini e il loro  uso:

> “*Quella che le serve, signora, è una nuova tipologia di lampadina”.*
>
> ***Tipologia*** è una di quelle parole che si usano impropriamente per fare impressione. L’elettricista in questione avrebbe dovuto dire “le serve un nuovo ***tipo*** di lampadina” ma ha usato una parola sbagliata che, essendo più complicata, lo faceva sentire più importante.
>
> ***La tipologia*** infatti è quello studio che permette la classificazione
> per tipi: tipologia linguistica, tipologia botanica. Probabilmente non
> esiste, ma nel caso esistesse la tipologia di lampadina dovrebbe
> essere uno studio, probabilmente universitario, tendente a
> classificare le varie lampadine esistenti in natura. E non vi sembra
> un po’ ecessivo mandare la povera signora all’università per cambiare
> lampadina?

Comment: Non è l'unico caso: “problematica” invece di “problema”, “utilizzo” invece di “uso” e tante altre.

Comment: @egreg si, infatti l’articolo dice che ***tipologia è una di quelle parole chi si usano impropriamente***.

Comment: @egreg:  E forse anche a volte "distinguo" per "distinzione" (come in quel esempio delle mamme)?

Comment: “Metodologia” per “metodo”, “minimale” per “minimo”, “modalità” per “modo”, “quantitativo” per “quantità”, “similare” per “simile”...

Comment: @DaG: Penso che questo sia una moda anche in altre lingue. Per esempio, ho visto scritti del comune di Barcellona che annunciavano lavori per modificare la "semaforització" della strada, parolina molto facile di pronunciare che non si trova neanche sui dizionari (invece di parlare semplicemente di "semàfors", cioè, semafori).

Comment: @Charo: Non mi stupirei se vedessi anche qualche comune italiano vantarsi dei lavori di semaforizzazione...

Comment: Ah, @DaG, ma il termine appare in qualche [dizionario italiano](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/semaforizzazione.html): bella parolina! A quanto pare, si tratta di "burocratese", però. Sto scoprendo che il lessico relativo ai semafori è davvero ricco: "semaforizzare", "semaforico", ...

Comment: @dag però "..izzazione" indica la trasformazione, l'applicazione, non l'oggetto stesso. Come si farebbe a dire "i lavori di aggiunta dei semafori" senza usare "semafori"? Il termine non è bello, però efficace. Potrebbero essere "semaforazione" o "semaforatura", che però anche loro non esistono.

Comment: @Charo *distinguo* contro *distinzione* è tutt'un'altra storia (ti piacciono i due apostrofi consecutivi?): *distinguo* (rispetto a distinzione) ha ben altra dignità d'esistere, ma soprattutto non significa una cosa totalmente diversa.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Non sono mai riuscita a sapere quale sia il significato esatto di "semaforització". Se significa lo stesso di "semaforizzazione", il caso che ho in mente era un mal uso di questa parola: era una frase in cui si doveva usare "semàfors" al posto di "semaforització". Lasciamo perdere, però.