# Sull'uso e senso di "con buona pace che"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

**Riassunto:** In questa domanda chiedo:

- L'espressione "con buona pace che" si usa?
- Se la risposta alla domanda precedente è affermativa, che senso ha e come si usa questa espressione?

---

Un po' di tempo fa, ascoltai qualcuno pronunciare una frase con la locuzione "con buona pace che". Questa espressione attirò la mia attenzione perché non l'avevo mai sentita o vista.

Non sono in grado di riprodurre la frase esatta, ma era simile a questa che ho trovato su [questo sito web](http://daniele.freeshell.org/rec/2009-triboot-macosx-gnulinux-windows.html) nel senso che iniziava con le parole "con buona pace che":

> Con buona pace che buona parte della pubblicità di Apple si basava proprio sul vantarsi di non usare Intel.

Ricercando su Google "con buona pace che" se ne possono trovare altri esempi, come questo, tratto da un  [articolo di Luciana Grosso](https://www.ilfoglio.it/esteri/2020/04/15/news/e-poi-come-andata-in-wisconsin-313134/), in cui si legge (grassetto mio):

> Non solo nell’elezione più importante, quella per un seggio alla Corte Suprema, ha vinto la giudice dem (lato Sanders) Jill Karofsky, ma soprattutto è andata a votare un sacco di gente, soprattutto per posta e lo ha fatto per i democratici, con il risultato di far dichiarare al Presidente che meno si vota per posta meglio è (**con buona pace che** lui stesso risulta aver votato per posta più volte).

Non capisco il senso di questa locuzione né in quali situazioni si possa usare.

Su alcuni dizionari, ho trovato la definizione di "con buona pace di", ma non mi sembra sia esattamente lo stesso (forse sì, ma io non lo capisco: per questa ragione posto una domanda):

- Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pace):

> *Con vostra buona p.*, *con buona p. di*, senza risentimenti, senza voler offendere, senza che qualcuno se ne abbia a male (per lo più ironicam.): *ho riscosso un grande successo, con buona p. degli invidiosi*.

- Sul [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/con-buona-pace-di):

> **con buona pace di** 
> loc.prep. 
> CO 
> spec. iron., senza voler offendere o contrariare qcn.: ha fatto un ottimo lavoro, con buona pace dei suoi colleghi

- Sul [dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/P/pace.shtml):

> **con buona pace di ...** 
> Senza offesa per nessuno; anche con il permesso, con l'autorizzazione di qualcuno. Quasi sempre ironico, con il significato opposto per sottolineare un dispetto, prendersi una rivincita, per scavalcare un rivale del quale ci si sente più forti, più abili, più furbi e così via.

- Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000327.jpg):

> – *Con  buona  pace  di  qualcuno*;  *con  pace,  pace  a qualcuno*;  *salva  pace  di  qualcuno*:  formula  attenuativa   per   introdurre   un’affermazione   sgra­devole   o   contrastante   con   l’opinione   espressa
> da tale persona o attribuitale.

Se ne parla anche sul [sito dell’Associazione Culturale Italiano Semplicemente](https://italianosemplicemente.com/2018/02/11/con-buona-pace/), che, però, non so fino a che punto sia affidabile.

A dire il vero, non capisco neanche come si usa in pratica la locuzione "con buona pace di": per questo ragione ho posto [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13192/).

Ma, di "con buona pace che", non sono riuscita a trovare nulla al riguardo.

A volte i dizionari non riflettono ancora l'uso che si fa di un certo termine o espressione. Un esempio molto interessante per la lingua spagnola si trova in [questa risposta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/es-bizarro-en-alg%c3%ban-caso-la-traducci%c3%b3n-de-bizarre), che è stata appena aggiornata: i dizionari di spagnolo non raccogliono ancora l'accezione di "bizarro" come un aggettivo per indicare qualcosa di stravagante o che attira l'attenzione per la sua stranezza. Ma questo uso è tanto frequente che la RAE ha detto in un tuit che sarà incorporato al dizionario.

Quindi, vorrei sapere semplicemente se "per buona pace che" si usa, nello stesso modo che l'OP di quella domanda su Spanish.SE chiedeva quattro anni fa su quel uso dello spagnolo "bizarro". Poi, ognuno può avere le sue opinioni sull'opportunità di usare espressioni o accezioni di termini che non appaiono sui dizionari  (ma non è questo l'oggetto della domanda). Chiedo se questa espressione si usa o non si usa, non un giudizio su se questo uso è "corretto" o "non corretto".

Faccio altri esempi perché si possa capire meglio cosa sto domandando. Se qualcuno chiede "l'espressione *peritarsi di* si usa intendendo dire *prendersi la briga di*?", alla luce di quanto si è discusso al riguardo di [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12849), io risponderei di sì, che si utilizza a volte in questo modo, ma che questo uso non è generalmente accettato.
Partendo di questa [altra domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12889) si potrebbe chiedere se si usa *tipologia* intendendo dire *tipo* e la risposta sarebbe anche affermativa, sebbene sia un uso improprio.

Se l'espressione veramente si  adopera nella forma "con buona pace che", potreste spiegare come si usa e che senso ha, con alcuni esempi?

Giusto per chiarire: non sto chiedendo sul significato delle due frasi che ho citato all'inizio del post. Non ho particolare interesse a sapere cosa vogliono dire esattamente. Vorrei sapere se "con buona pace che" è un'espressione in uso e, se fosse così, come si utilizza e che senso ha, spiegato con alcuni esempi (che possono essere diversi di quelli che ho riportato).

Comment: Abuso, vorrai dire.

Comment: Scusa, @egreg: non capisco cosa vuoi dire. Si tratta di un mal uso dell'espressione che si trova sui dizionari?

Comment: La locuzione “con buona pace di qualcuno” si adopera. Chi si deve mettere il cuore in pace deve essere una persona (o un gruppo di persone), non ha senso adoperare una proposizione oggettiva al posto della specificazione di persona.

Comment: Va bene, @egreg, se è così, modifico la domanda  (l'ho già fatto).

Comment: “Con buona pace che” è una locuzione poco comune ma si possono  trovare  vari esempi: https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&ei=Ci86X8myNoPSkwW3qJaoAw&q=%22con+buona+pace+che%22+&oq=%22con+buona+pace+che%22+&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjoCCClQyy1YoDlgkD5oAHAAeACAAW2IAbsCkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp - il senso è lo stesso della più comune “con buona pace di” dove l’oggetto non è definito e si riferisce in generale a tutti coloro che la pensassero diversamente.

Comment: Grazie, @Hachi: il problema è che, come ho detto nella domanda, malgrado aver trovato tutte quelle spiegazioni dei dizionari, non capisco neanche l'uso dell'espressione più comune. È la prima volta in vita mia che incontro queste espressioni. Immagino si tratti di qualcosa di molto semplice per i madrelingua, ma per me non lo è.

Comment: Scusa, pensavo il problema fosse l’uso della variante con il “che” invece che “di”.

Comment: @Hachi La seconda citazione che vedo da Google è “Con buona pace che le pagine saranno bilanciate uguali, togliendo eventuali micro-imperfezioni dovuto dal fotto di lavorare su due immagini…” che mi sembra italiano molto zoppicante (anche eliminando i due ovvi refusi). Non vedo esempi davvero “autorevoli”.

Comment: Su Google c’è un po’ di tutto ovviamente. Guarda l’esempio su  Maria Antonietta (che per qualche motivo non riesco a fare copia incolla.)

Comment: @Hachi:    Veramente il problema sono tutte e due: semplicemente la prima volta che mi sono imbattuta in questa espressione è stato nella forma "con buona pace che" e non avevo idea dell'esistenza di "con buona pace di". Purtroppo non mi ho subito segnato la frase esatta e adesso non la ricordo. A me è sembrato che la persona che l'ha detto parlasse bene l'italiano, ma può darsi che fossi sbagliata su questo e si trattasse di un esempio d'italiano cattivo. Non ho idea su questo.

Comment: Non si tratta di un italiano “cattivo” ma di una locuzione meno comune. Guarda la frase in grassetto nell'articolo allegato: https://www.scintilena.com/risolto-il-mistero-dellantico-tunnel-sotterraneo-dello-stretto-di-messina/02/18/

Comment: Premesso che “con buona pace che” mi suona ostrogoto, in particolare la frase “Con buona pace che buona parte etc.” da vari punti di vista è un esempio di italiano inelegante (oltre alla “buona pace che”, la ripetizione di “buona”, i due infiniti sostantivati...). Niente di agrammaticale, ma varie cose che un buon redattore limerebbe.

Comment: Non mi sembra che sia stato fatto notare che tra i vari esempi ci sono due usi molto diversi dal punto di vista sintattico di “con buona pace che”. Quello degli esempi menzionati nella domanda (che è quello che io trovo ostrogoto) di fatto sottintende un “del fatto” (“con buona pace (del fatto) che lui stesso risulta...”). Quello del sito di speleologia (grazie @Hachi) mi risulta solo poco familiare, non ostrogoto: “con buona pace” ha un senso a sé stante (nel senso che non regge una subordinata) simile, a quel che pare, a “con una certa sicurezza”.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; let's [continue this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111896/discussion-on-question-by-charo-sul-senso-e-uso-di-con-buona-pace-che-e-con-b).

Comment: Premetto che va fatta la distinzione di cui parla sopra Dag, e sono d'accordo sul fatto che *con buona pace che* per dire *con buona pace del fatto che* suona ostrogoto. Io non ho mai sentito questa frase, e ho il dubbio che si tratti di un uso locale, regionale, mi suona come il *piuttosto che* nel senso di *oppure* che si sente in Lombardia: chi non è di lì e non lo conosce non lo capisce, capisce un'altra cosa  (e non mi pare sia italiano).  Suggerirei di controllare, dove possibile, la regione di chi lo dice. *Con buona pace di* invece è una espressione comune, almeno a me del tutto nota.

Answer (score -1):

Per rispondere nel caso specifico occorrerebbe un poco più di contesto; vorrei sottolineare che negli esempi che hai trovato, la frase assume sempre una connotazione ironica.

L'esempio che tira in ballo la Apple si riferisce secondo me al fatto che la Apple si è sempre vantata di non utilizzare processori Intel, ma...    ad un certo punto (IMac)... ha iniziato ad utilizzarli! Ovviamente reclamizzando la grande "novità" e sconfessando quindi tutte le campagne pubblicitarie precedenti!

Potremmo dire che le campagne pubblicitarie precedenti sono state diciamo relegate alla "buona pace" dell'oblio.

Un espressione con significato simile potrebbe essere "alla faccia che..."

Comment: Scusa, @Riccardo: forse non sono riuscita a spiegarmi bene nella domanda. Non è che mi interessi capire il significato di quella frase in particolare, che era soltanto un esempio. Quello che vorrei sapere è qual è il senso e come si usa l'espressione "con buona pace che", con alcuni esempi (possono essere diversi di quelli della domanda). Ho appena aggiunto al post un'altro esempio che ho trovato. Ma insisto: non ho particolare interesse in capire queste due frasi, per cui la risposta può spiegare come si usa questa espressione con esempi diversi (se manca contesto a quelli della domanda).

Comment: Allora, "con buona pace che" ha un significato e uso simile all'espressione "alla faccia che"? Il problema è che anche "alla faccia che" è assolutamente sconosciuta per me: non ho idea su cosa voglia dire.

Comment: @Charo per come la vedo io, i modi di dire corretti (diciamo così) sono "con buona pace di" e "alla faccia di". La forma con "che" è una forzatura che slega (anacoluto?); sarebbe meglio scrivere "con buona pace del fatto che" e simili.

Comment: Riccardo, dove si usa “alla faccia che”?

Comment: Per favore, potresti aggiungere qualche dettaglio in più su quello che  sto chiedendo nella domanda? Nel modo in cui è adesso, non sono per niente sicura che questo sia veramente una risposta alla mia domanda. E, poi, come ho detto in un commento precedente, "alla faccia che" è assolutamente incomprensibile per me.

Comment: E cosa significa  «alla "buona pace" dell'oblio»? Anche questa espressione è assolutamente incomprensibile per me. Devo capire che il senso di "con buona pace che" ha qualcosa a che vedere con un invito a dimenticare qualcosa?

Comment: Quindi, in questa risposta, tutto quello che fa riferimento al significato della locuzione "con buona pace che" mi risulta incomprensibile. E continuo a non avere idea su come si usa (se veramente si usa). Il mio dubbio è sul significato e uso di "con buona pace che". Non ho mai chiesto cosa significa esattamente la frase sulla Apple. Puoi vederlo nella prima versione della domanda.

Comment: Poi ho aggiunto un esempio in più e la domanda su se veramente si usa (a causa di tanti commenti che sembravano dire che forse non si usa o è italiano cattivo).

Answer (score -1):

L’uso è legittimo, ancorché di registro colloquiale e non raccomandabile.
La frase in questo caso NON è “con buona pace di qualcuno (individuato)” ma “Con buona pace (sua/di tutti).
Il “che” introduce una proposizione dichiarativa che chiarisce il motivo della “buona pace”, che è usato sarcasticamente.
La frase si potrebbe parafrasare così “a dispetto del fatto che lui stesso ha votato per posta più volte”.

“Con buona pace” in generale copre una risma di significati. La chiave per comprenderli è capire che la buona pace può essere naturale e volontaria o innaturale/*forzata*. Quanto più si può supporre che la pace del soggetto sia “autentica”/naturale/volntaria, tanto più l’espressione assume il senso “con la sua benedizione/approvazione/beneplacito/senza offenderlo”; quanto più si può supporre che non sia una pace naturale/volontaria, la frase assume il significato “ignorandolo/a suo dispetto”.